# What is the easiest way to subtract time in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, math, timespan

I'm trying to put together a tool that will help me make work schedules.  What is the easiest way to solve the following?

- 8:00am + 5 hours = 1:00pm
- 5:00pm - 2 hours = 3:00pm
- 5:30pm - :45 = 4:45

and so on.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

These can all be done with [`DateTime.Add(TimeSpan)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx) since it supports positive and negative timespans.

```
DateTime original = new DateTime(year, month, day, 8, 0, 0);
DateTime updated = original.Add(new TimeSpan(5,0,0));

DateTime original = new DateTime(year, month, day, 17, 0, 0);
DateTime updated = original.Add(new TimeSpan(-2,0,0));

DateTime original = new DateTime(year, month, day, 17, 30, 0);
DateTime updated = original.Add(new TimeSpan(0,-45,0));
```

Or you can also use the [`DateTime.Subtract(TimeSpan)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae6246z1(v=vs.110).aspx) method analogously.

Comment: ok so where did i go wrong. i added a datetimepicker and assigned its value to a datetime variable. now the math methods aren't showing up

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - probably worth posting some code, this is a slightly different question than date-time arithmetic

Comment: @Sinaesthetic When you use a DateTimePicker, bear in mind it can show _either_ date _or_ time-of-day, but maintains a Value composed of *both*... if you're using the Value property you may need to subtract one or the other component first.

Comment: In the third example the OP wants to subtract 45 minutes, why in this answer I don't see a negative value? Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 33):

Check out all the DateTime methods here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

> **`Add`**  Returns a new DateTime that adds the value of the specified TimeSpan to the value of this instance.
>
> **`AddDays`**  Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance.
>
> **`AddHours`** Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of hours to the value of this instance.
>
> **`AddMilliseconds`**  Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of milliseconds to the value of this instance.
>
> **`AddMinutes`**   Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of minutes to the value of this instance.
>
> **`AddMonths`**    Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of months to the value of this instance.
>
> **`AddSeconds`**   Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of seconds to the value of this instance.
>
> **`AddTicks`** Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of ticks to the value of this instance.
>
> **`AddYears`** Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of years to the value of this instance.

Comment: For everyone that comes over this: You can use these functions above and use a negative value to subtract, as long as the instance hasn't been initialised to DateTime.MinValue

Answer (score 12):

Hi if you are going to subtract only Integer value from DateTime then you have to write code like this

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2)
```

Here I am subtracting 2 hours from the current date and time

Answer (score 9):

This works too:

```
System.DateTime dTime = DateTime.Now();

// tSpan is 0 days, 1 hours, 30 minutes and 0 second.
System.TimeSpan tSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0, 1, 3, 0); 

System.DateTime result = dTime + tSpan;
```

To subtract a year:

```
DateTime DateEnd = DateTime.Now;
DateTime DateStart = DateEnd - new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the TimeSpan object to capture your initial time element and use the methods such as `AddHours` or `AddMinutes`. To substract 3 hours, you will do `AddHours(-3)`. To substract 45 mins, you will do `AddMinutes(-45)`

Comment: `Use the TimeSpan object to capture your initial time element` - do you mean `DateTime`?

Comment: I am referring to System.TimeSpan type

Comment: But the initial time is an instant e.g. 8:00pm rather than a time span e.g. 45 minutes. (Also apologies, I just realised how old a post this is.)

Comment: But that's what I meant. You will write ts = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0) for 8am or ts = new Timespan(20, 0, 0) for 8pm, then you will do ts.AddMinutes(45)

Comment: Eh... I suppose that works OK if you genuinely don't care about the date, but that's semantically not what a timespan represents, and it would really boost your [WTFpm](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m) rating.

Comment: Not disagreeing with your comment :) Like you said, been a long while last I answered this post. At that time, it was a spontaneous response to answer the question specifically just on performing simple operation on time.

Comment: Yeah, I know exactly what you mean there. I won't pretend some of my old answers wouldn't provide a few WTFs themselves :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
namespace dateandtime
{

    class DatesTime
    {

        public static DateTime Substract(DateTime now, int hours,int minutes,int seconds)
        {
            TimeSpan T1 = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
            return now.Subtract(T1);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Substract(DateTime.Now, 36, 0, 0).ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime original = new DateTime(year, month, day, 8, 0, 0);
DateTime updated = original.Add(new TimeSpan(5,0,0));

DateTime original = new DateTime(year, month, day, 17, 0, 0);
DateTime updated = original.Add(new TimeSpan(-2,0,0));

DateTime original = new DateTime(year, month, day, 17, 30, 0);
DateTime updated = original.Add(new TimeSpan(0,-45,0));

Answer (score -1):

TimeLeftToOpen=  new TimeSpan(TimeLeftToOpen.Hours, TimeLeftToOpen.Minutes, TimeLeftToOpen.Seconds - 1);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).