# how to write a query which groups dates by week

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, group-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c#: whats the easiest way to subtract time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993226/c-whats-the-easiest-way-to-subtract-time)

I have a table containing a field of dates and some other field (not important to mention), and I need two reports:
1.based on month
2.based on week

I have done the report number 1

my question is HOW CAN I ACHIEVE report 2, I need something that gives me this:

let's say we have dates from 2001/01/01 to 2001/01/31

I want to get all days grouped by week for example if 2001/01/01 is Sunday i want groups like:

1st week : 2001/01/01 - 2001/01/02 - ... - 2001/01/07
2nd week : 2001/01/08 - ... - 2001/01/14
3rd week : 2001/01/15 - ... - 2001/01/21
4th week : 2001/01/22 - ... - 2001/01/28
5th week : 2001/01/29 - 2001/01/30 - 2001/01/31

Comment: @Leppie, Some Coders gotta find out some day, remember your first time :P

Comment: @leppi why didn't that come to my mind? :D thanks anyway for every single answer.

Comment: It is math. `1 + -1 = 0`. You still 'Add' days, however with a negative value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass negative number in AddDays method it will subtract that number of days from date object.

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
```

or

```
 DateTimeObj.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Off topic, but *always* use UtcNow! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply insert negative value in `AddDays` function in following ways:

```
 DateTimeObj.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Short one would be

```
DateTimeObj.AddDays(-1);
```

You can specify negative days also

Answer (score 2):

This helps

`DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);`

Comment: Off topic, but *always* use UtcNow! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
dateTimeObj.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Off topic, but *always* use UtcNow! :)