# How can I subtract 6 hour from the current time?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c#: whats the easiest way to subtract time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993226/c-whats-the-easiest-way-to-subtract-time)

Suppose I have this time :

```
07/12/2012 - 00:30:45
```

I'd like to subtract 6 hour, such as 06/12/2012 - 18:30:45. I see there are .AddHours() but not SubHours(). How can I do it?

Comment: You can "add" a negative number :)

Comment: `.AddHours(-6)` ?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can use [AddHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx), it will subtract hours if negative number is passed.

```
DateTime dt1 = dt.AddHours(-6);
```

Comment: Don't matter about it! Recently stackoverflow users are a bit crazy :) Just I don't have think about it on this early cold morning! Thank you

Answer (score 33):

You can use negative values to subtract time

```
myTime.AddHours(-6);
```