# Get datetime value from X days go?

Tags: c#, date, math, datetime, datetime-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c#: whats the easiest way to subtract time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993226/c-whats-the-easiest-way-to-subtract-time)

I want

```
MyNewDateValue = MyDateNow - MyDateInteger;
```

Example
Today is the 22nd of December 2012

If MyDateIneger value is 120, MyNewDateValue, will return the datetime 120 days ago.

Comment: I believe the third answer to the above question would give you what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3993240/211627

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
MyNewDateValue = MyDateNow.AddDays(-MyDateInteger);
```

Answer (score 25):

Please look into [`DateTime.AddDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
DateTime oneTwentyDaysAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-120);
```

or in general

```
DateTime nDaysAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-N);
// where N is the number of days
```

Answer (score 4):

```
MyNewDateValue = MyDateNow.AddDays(-120);
```

or

```
MyNewDateValue = MyDateNow.AddDays(myVar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this frnd

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime newdt = new DateTime();
TimeSpan tim = new TimeSpan(120,0,0,0,0);
newdt = dt.Add(tim);
MessageBox.Show(newdt.ToString());
```

ADD.timespan will help you to add or subtract days from today.