# How to get difference from 24 hours time format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timespan

I have two time(getting from Time Picker)

```
Time1=22:10
Time2=05:10
```

total time difference  I need  as `07:00`

For example from `10:10 pm` to `05:10 am` there is a difference of `7` hours. Like this same way am asking how to find if it is in a 24 hours format?

How can I achieve it? In 12 hours case I am fine. But I do not know how to do it in 24 hours format?? It is a web application.

Comment: Surely there is some property you can set, or some format you can parse. Have a look at NodaTime as well on github

Comment: You question is about the 12 hour format, but you say the 12 hour format is fine? Did you confuse both cases?

Comment: Is the time difference is 7:00 or 17:00?

Comment: @SelvaTS I assume the second time is always later than the first one.

Comment: Just saw it... *"22:10 PM"* is **no** valid time. It's either *"10:10 PM"* or *"22:10"*.

Comment: @Mario in this case, then we need to add one more day and subtract the previous date.

Comment: @Mario,Its 24 hours format see the time 22:10 PM (means 10:10 PM) and 05:10 Am.

Comment: You should explain a bit more what the actual problem is. I have the same problem as Selva. You dont know if Time2 is always > than Time1 or it could be earlier.

Comment: @SaraJohn No, 24 hour format doesn't know "AM" or "PM" - it must not be there. I should know, I'm from good old Germany and most people can't even handle 12 hour format (it's like reversed compared to the US :D).

Comment: @Mario, Pardon I have edited my question

Comment: Maybe this could help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993226/c-whats-the-easiest-way-to-subtract-time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formatting *only* applies when you try to get string representation of your `DateTime` or your `TimeSpan`. Difference between these two type instance doesn't effect about formatting.

If these values are `TimeSpan` like;

```
TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0);
TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
TimeSpan result = ts1 - ts2;
```

`result` will be `{15:00:00}` as a `TimeSpan` which has `15` as an [`Hour` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

By the way `AM/PM` formats only applies for `DateTime` values not `TimeSpan`. A `TimeSpan` is a *time interval*.

For example; we can't say *before noon or after noon* for a `TimeSpan` value because it doesn't make sense *at all*.

If you have a `DateTime` values like these (And I think these examples will match on your values since you wanna get 7 hours difference between `22:10` and `05:10`)

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2015, 2, 21, 5, 10, 0);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 10, 0);
TimeSpan result = dt1 - dt2;
```

`result` will be `{07:00:00}` as a `TimeSpan` which has `7` as an `Hour` property.

Comment: That's actually an interesting approach, with both times being time spans. Considering the date doesn't matter, this is kinda neat. :)

Comment: @Mario Yes, even if they are `DateTime` their subtraction will be `TimeSpan` as a result. Since `TimeSpan` is _time interval_, it _can't_ have any `AM/PM` part even if we format it. We can't say _before noon or after noon_ as a `TimeSpan` value.

Comment: @SaraJohn Are these `Time1` and `Time2` values `DateTime`? I think your `Time2` is one day after from `Time1` since you wanna get `7` hours as a difference. Updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: @Soner Gönül, Its not a DateTime this value I am fetching from ccl time picker

Comment: @SaraJohn If they are `string`, you can parse them first with `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` first. Both types have `Parse` methods. You can check their documentations.

Comment: @Soner Gönül, Thank you for your support. Myself found a solution for this, That I have added below. Please check weather it is helpful or not..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71324/discussion-between-sara-john-and-soner-gonul).